# PayPal .Net transfers from a customer to another customer

Tags: .net, reactjs, rest, .net-core, paypal

I want to make a web application (backend - .Net Core & frontend - React) in which I want to make money transfers between two customers using PayPal. How do I do this? How do I specify that a payment is between two customers? Or should I be between the customers in sense that I receive money from buyer and send money to seller (two consecutive transfers)? Do I have to force customers to give me PayPal accounts' data in order to make transfers later on? I could not find any information on PayPal website about such a case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to let one user pay another would be with a buy now equivalent link, e.g.

```
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_xclick&item_name=transfer&business=receiveremail@goeshere.com&amount=100&currency_code=USD
```

The email of the payer will be filled in from their own browser cookies, so you don't need to worry about that. They just need to sign in or use PayPal's One Touch

---

A more robust solution than a simple link would be to implement a REST API, with a `payee` parameter specifying the recipient's email.

Comment: But what if I want to get a commission from the buyer? And could you be more specific please (I am new in online payments and don't understand you very well :( )

Comment: If you want to get commission then that is a much more complicated problem than originally described, and you run into double fee problems or approval issues, and business model viability issues.

Since you are new to online payments, my best advice is to find a more experienced person to help you, because what you are trying to accomplish is not easy, and is likely to fail.